# Why Lakshmana did not tell the name of Ravana to Hanuman even he knows?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana, valmiki, lakshmana

Jataayu tells to Rama that Ravana abducted the Sita

> "Oh, boy Rama, blest is your eternality, for whom you are searching as
>   with the search of a rejuvenescent herb in the vast of forest, **Ravana
>   stole that lady** and my lives, too... [[3-67-15]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga67/aranya_67_frame.htm)

But later Lakshmana tell to Hanuman that they do not know who abducted the Sita

> "He who aspires to keep up the well-being of all the beings, and he
>   who is merited for all comforts and respectability is now devoid of
>   his prosperity and predisposed to forest dwelling... such as he is,
>   **his wife is abducted by a guise changing demon in a lonely place, of
>   whom we know not... we know not which demon stole his wife.**.. [[4-4-13,
>   14]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga4/kishkindha_4_frame.htm)

The only possibilities I can think are either *Lakshmana did not hear the conversation between Rama and Jataayu* or *Lakshmana is intentionally hiding the truth*.

But there is no chance for the former reason because Rama told the following words to Lakshmana

> "Lakshmana, this eagle which has dashed to rescue Seetha in order to
>   render help to me is slain by that brute-forced **Ravana**, only because
>   of me, you see... [[3-68-22]](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga68/aranya_68_frame.htm)

And there is also a less chance for the latter reason because of the reason that Lakshmana may not speak untuth that too infront of Rama.

Then what is the actual reason (or strategy) for Lakshmana to hide the information about Ravana abducting Sita?

Comment: I can think of 2 different reasons for this: One is that he just met Hanuman and does not trust him and is intentionally hiding this information, as no one should reveal tactically important information to someone they don't trust. Second could be that Lakshman doesn't know who Ravan is, means he may know the name that some demon named Ravan kidnapped Sita, but doesn't know who he actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Sri Hanuman approaches Sri Raama and Lakshmana in the form of an ascetic.

> कपि रूपम् परित्यज्य हनुमान् मारुतात्मजः |
>   भिक्षु रूपम् ततो भेजे शठबुद्धितया कपिः || ४-३-२
>
> Casting off his monkey's semblance Air-god's son Hanuma attained the persona of an ascetic, for that monkey is incredulous in mind about Raghava-s

Sri Hanuman speaks to them while assessing the physical characteristics, strength of the 2 brothers Sri Raama and Lakshmana and at the same time the latter were also assessing in the same manner about the former.

In the midst of this unpopulated thick forest, an ascetic comes in, talks at length, that too without offence to the scriptures, will definitely raise the doubt in two brothers.

This particular questioner is not definitely any ascetic or sage, because he is roaming in deep forests, rather than around some villages where he may get some charities. And also that, generally ascetics will talk, only when they are talked to, but this one with some purpose behind, is almost pestering to reveal the identity of the intruders.

> राजर्षि देव प्रतिमौ तापसौ संशित व्रतौ || ४-३-५
>   देशम् कथम् इमम् प्राप्तौ भवन्तौ वर वर्णिनौ |
>   त्रासयन्तौ मृग गणान् अन्याम् च वन चारिणः || ४-३-६
>
> "You two look like kingly saints, or deities by your build, ascetics with blest vows, but with ideal complexions... how come you arrived at this countryside scaring the herds of animals and other inhabitants of this forest.."

Hence, the brothers might have considered Sri Hanuman to be another demon or anyone sent by somebody, for they already knew about the Vali-Sugreeva episode, through Kabandha.

So to be on safe side, Lakshmana might not have revealed the name of the demon, who abducted Sita.